# Select count date from multiple where conditions for each day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have lot of coupons. I would like to learn for each day how many coupons from each campaign have been received by users. But I cannot write something like assigned_date for each select row

```
SELECT count(id)                                                  as number_of_coupons,
       DATE_FORMAT(assigned_date, '%d-%m-%Y')                     as date,
       (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM coupon WHERE campaign_id = 1 AND assigned_date=THIS MUST BE SOMETHING) as campaign_1,
       (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM coupon WHERE campaign_id = 2 AND assigned_date=THIS MUST BE SOMETHING) as campaign_2
FROM coupon
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(assigned_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
order by STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%m-%Y') DESC
```

So the result will be something like. How can I achieve this result?

```
+-------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| number of coupons |    date    |  campaign_1 | campaign2 |
+-------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|               156 | 12-10-2019 |        6980 |       100 |
|               177 | 11-10-2019 |        6980 |       100 |
|                44 | 10-10-2019 |        6980 |       100 |
|                94 | 09-10-2019 |        6980 |       100 |
|                93 | 08-10-2019 |        6980 |       100 |
+-------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I also removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Have you read my question? You got it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing what your data structure looks like, I can only speculate on what the solution should be.  However, my guess is that a query such as the following is what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cv.id) as number_of_coupons,
       DATE_FORMAT(cv.assigned_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.campaign_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as campaign_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.campaign_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as campaign_2
FROM coupon_vault cv LEFT JOIN
     coupons c
     ON cv.coupon_id = c.coupon_id
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(cv.assigned_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
ORDER BY MIN(cv.assigned_date);
```

It is quite possible that the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is unnecessary and `COUNT()` would suffice.

Both Postgres and MySQL (your original tag) have reasonable alternatives for the `SUM(CASE . . .)`.  However, you have not specified your database, so I'm sticking with the code that works in both databases.

Comment: The problem is it gives me the same values of campaing_1 campaing_2 for each day. They must be totally different.

Comment: Why SUM works fine but COUNT gives the same campaign_1 campaign_2 count?